Estimating a solution to an Euler-type ODE
Let $f$ be a continuous function in $L^2([1,\infty)$ satisfying $\sup_{r\geq 1} r|f(r)| <\infty$. Let $\ell$ be a positive integer and $a$ be a real number.
Let $u(r)$ be a function on $[1,\infty)$ solving the following BVP:
$$r^2u''(r)+2ru'(r) - \ell(\ell+1) u(r) = f(r), \quad r\in [1,\infty)$$
$$u(1)= a, \quad \lim_{r\to \infty} u(r) = 0$$
We should be able to estimate the solution $u$ by $f$ and $a$. I want to understand precisely how $\ell$ will appear in this estimate. (In a certain context, $\ell$ corresponds to an angular derivative of some function in $\mathbb{R}^3$)
I am speculating the following: there exists a constant $C$ independent of $\ell$, $a$, $u$ and $f$ satisfying
$$\ell \sup_{r\geq 1}r|u(r)| + \sup_{r\geq 1}r^2|u'(r)| \leq C(\ell^{-1}\sup_{r\geq 1} r|f(r)| + \ell^{-1}\lVert f\rVert_{L^2} + \ell|a|)$$
Can anyone verify if this is true? How would I prove this estimate (or the correct one in case the above is incorrect)?

This boundary value problem for the Euler equation can be solved explicitly, why do you need an estimate? What is the range of your $\ell$? Is it real, positive?

$\ell$ is a positive integer. I want this estimate because it will eventually imply regularity results on solutions to the Poisson equation in $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus B_1$ equipped with an asymptotically flat metric $g$. In particular, if the forcing term has k angular derivatives in $L^2$ and $C^0$, then the solution and its derivative have $k+2$ and $k+1$ angular derivatives in $L^2$ and $C^0$. I haven't found such regularity results (where only angular derivatives are addressed) in the literature. (note the solution will have only 2 radial derivatives, but possibly much more angular ones.

Noticing the factorization $r^{-\ell} \frac{d}{dr} r^{2(\ell+1)} \frac{d}{dr} r^{-\ell} u(r) = f(r)$ (as a trick to avoid recalling the precise variation of constants formula), an integral representation of the solution with the desired asymptotic behavior is
$$\begin{aligned}
  u(r)
  &= \frac{A}{r^{\ell+1}}
     - r^\ell \int_r^\infty ds \, s^{-2(\ell+1)} \int_1^s dt \, t^\ell f(t) \\
  &= \frac{A}{r^{\ell+1}}
     - \frac{r^\ell}{2\ell+1} \int_r^\infty ds\, s^{-\ell-1} f(s)
     - \frac{r^{-\ell-1}}{2\ell+1} \int_1^r ds\, s^\ell f(s) \\
  r|u(r)|
  &\le \frac{|A|}{r^{\ell}} + \left(
        r^{\ell+1} \int_r^\infty ds\, s^{-\ell-2}
        + r^{-\ell} \int_1^r ds\, s^{\ell-1}
     \right) \frac{\sup_{s\ge 1} s|f(s)|}{2\ell+1} \\
  &\le \frac{|A|}{r^{\ell}} + \frac{\sup_{s\ge 1} s|f(s)|}{\ell(\ell+1)}
\end{aligned}$$
The constant $A$ is fixed by the condition $u(1)=a$,
$$\begin{aligned}
  u(1) &= A - \frac{1}{2\ell+1} \int_1^\infty ds\, s^{-\ell-1} f(s) = a \\
  A &= a + \frac{1}{2\ell+1} \langle s^{-\ell-1}, f(s) \rangle_{L^2} \\
  |A| &\le a + \frac{\|s^{-\ell-1}\|_{L^2} \|f\|_{L^2}}{2\ell+1}
      = a + \frac{\|f\|_{L^2}}{(2\ell+1)^{3/2}}
\end{aligned}$$
Completing the bound for $r^2|u'(r)|$ can be done analogously and checking the original guessed estimate is left as an exercise.

Thank you! It's interesting that both the $C^0$ and $L^2$ norm of the forcing term appear.

@Laithy It is a matter of preference. In retrospect, I switched between usual Cauchy-Schwarz $L_2$-$L_2$ estimates and $L_1$-$L_\infty$ estimates somewhat randomly. But I think you can choose either one or the other, when the choice comes up. Just be careful to keep track of the $r$-dependent finite integration domain in $\int_1^r ds, s^\ell f(s)$. In the naive $r\to\infty$ limit, this integral diverges. Also of course, as a running assumption, the value of $\ell$ has to be sufficiently large (at least in real part) for all the steps to work.

Yes, I understand. I believe what you did above implies the estimate in the original post for any $\ell$. The hard part is to show that $C$ can be chosen independently of $\ell$ for large $\ell$.   Thank you for helping me (you have also helped me several times in the past :)  ).

Are there more robust techniques to prove this kind of estimate? I posted a similar question here with a similar ODE, but couldn't show it the same way.
